# How to mock a method that is returning a subscribe

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, jestjs, enzyme

I currently have a method that I wanted to test and mock but not sure how to do it

```
interaction
  .onEvent('DO_SOMETHING')
  .subscribe(async (items: Array<Item>) => {
    console.log(items)
  });

export declare class Interaction {
    onEvent<T = any>(eventName: string): Subscriber<T>;
}

export interface Subscriber<T> {
    subscribe(value?: Callback<[T]>, error?: Callback<any>, complete?: Callback<[]>): Unsubscriber;
}
```

I tried mocking it this way

```
    interaction: {
      onEvent: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ subscribe: jest.fn() }),
    },
```

The test itself is just running a snapshot which runs the mock interaction on render.

```
    const store = createStore();

    mount(
      <StoreProvider value={store}>
        <Plugin interaction={interaction} />
      </StoreProvider>,
    );

    await async.delay(100);

    expect(store.state).toMatchSnapshot();
```

but I'm getting an error telling me that *Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined]*. Can someone advise on what i'm missing?

Comment: If you include your test file, it'll be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks. Just updated. It's just a snapshot though running the method onMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an observable returned in an mocked implementation, you can do something like this:

```
jest.spyOn(yourObject, 'method').mockImplementation(() => of(response))
```

of() being an function from the rxjs package creating observables from values. Source: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of